# Swift Search UIScrollView for a UIImageView with specific attributes

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView with 1000 UIImages in it. These UIImages have a row and col attribute. How do I search the UIScrollView's UIImages for a specific row and col? (Then I will update the image) I am getting this error: For-in loop requires 'UIScrollView' to conform to 'Sequence'

Something like:

```
        for eachImageView in MyUIScrollView! {
        if eachImageView.row = searchrow {
            if eachImageView.col = searchcol {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

The MyUIScrollView subviews eachImageView row and col are just Int from a class:

```
class cellUIImageView: UIImageView {

var row: Int = 0
var col: Int = 0
...
```

Comment: Try to iterate through `MyUIScrollView!.subviews`. You should show some more code too, because we don't know what MyUIScrollView is, or how row and col properties are set.

Comment: When I use MyUIScrollView!.subviews I get  the error: Cannot convert sequence element type 'UIView' to expected type 'cellUIImageView'.

Answer (score 0):

First, a note: class names should begin upper-cased... use `CellUIImageView` instead of `cellUIImageView`.

Anyway...

You can find your view like this:

```
    let v2 = scroll.subviews.filter {
        ($0 as? CellUIImageView)?.row == searchrow && ($0 as? CellUIImageView)?.col == searchcol
    }
    guard v2.count == 1, let foundView = v2.first as? CellUIImageView else {
        print("CellUIImageView with row:", searchrow, "and col:", searchcol, "was not found!")
        return
    }
    // do something with it, such as
    foundView.image = replacementImage
```